# How can I check whether a specific field has two or more values? Pymongo, MongoDB

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo, querying

I have a question. Some background context: I am querying a database for a specific field whose value is of the type [User]. Where "User" is of type ObjectId(x) for some x. For example:

```
{  '_id': ObjectId(x)
   'field_1: value
   'field_2: [User_1]
}
```

However, field_2 can also have multiple Users within the brackets in other documents like so:

```
   'field_2': [User_1, User_2, User_3]
```

So my question is: If I need to narrow down the population, how can I search for the documents that have two or more "User" values in 'field_2'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mongo query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) in order to narrow down your results.

For your purposes, a combination of `$and`, `$size`, and `$not` should work.

```py
query = { '$and': [ 
    { 'field_2': { '$exists': 'true'} }, 
    { 'field_2': { '$not': { '$size':  0 } } },
    { 'field_2': { '$not': { '$size':  1 } } }
] } )
collection.find(query)
```